# Springboot application (Spring 2.1.4) HTTPS Enabled

Tags: java, spring-boot, https, jks, pkcs#12

I have to make my Spring boot application HTTPS enabled. For this task, I created a CSR and sent it to Security team of my employer. They provided a signed certificate ncf.cer to me. I was following steps from a website (https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/) and performed below steps.

1. Import `ncf.cer` into Java/JDK1.8/JRE/lib/security/cacerts (assuming it is JKS keystore)
   with alias ‘ncf’
2. In the code, placed `ncf.p12` into `src/main/resources`
3. Made below changes in `applications.properties`

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/keystore/ncf.p12  
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-alias=ncf
```

I am getting an error when I start the Springboot application:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
```

Can anyone please help me in getting the proper steps for making my application HTTPS enabled?

Comment: Remove `src/main/resources` from the path and use `classpath:ncf.p12` (assuming the file is directly in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: If I remove src/main/resources and replace it with classpath:ncf.p12 then I see below error:

"Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ncf.p12] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist"

Comment: he missed your keystore folder, try classpath:keystore/ncf.p12  or something like that or move it out of the keystore folder into the bare resources folder.

Comment: Didn't miss it as he first states he placed in in `src/main/resources` and not in the sub folder. Nonetheless if it cannot be found the path should include that folder (probably).

Comment: I tried changing the class path and It seems it is reading the ncf.p12 as well. I see original error again. Does it mean I need to import ncf.p12 as well inside cacerts ?
"Caused by: java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry"

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by importing .cer and .p12 certs in cacerts keystore. But unfortunately now I am getting another error. Now server is starting well but when I try to execute the code which involves hitting another 3rd party API which is on HTTPS. So when my code hits 3rd party API on HTTPS, it throws below error:

Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue finally. Below are the steps

1. import .cer into cacerts with an alias.
2. import .p12 into cacerts without providing alias. Here system will generate alias (long
   alphanumeric number) for you. Mention this alias number inside applicatins.properties.
3. Copy .p12 inside src/main/resoruces/keystore and then refer this path inside
   applications.properties.

Answer (score 0):

This error means your keystore doesn't contain the original private key.

The signed certificate `ncf.cer` is supposed to be imported into the original keystore where the cert request was generated. Is it `cacerts`? Typically this file only contains public keys of trusted certificates instead of the public/private key pair.

Once you have the signed certificate `ncf.cer` imported into the correct keystore, you can export into the PKCS12 format then use in your folder as `ncf.p12`. If you can share how the `ncf.cer` file was imported and `ncf.p12` was created, I can further help.